# Why isn't mainloop() at the start of your code instead of the end?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I understand how the function works itself, however, mainloop() is usually at the end of your code in modules like turtle and tkinter and you're required to put it at the end or there will be a syntax error and/or the remaining code is discarded

Since Python is a step by step process, wouldn't it make more sense for it to be put at the start?

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking.  I believe this is because you are not understanding how the flow of execution occurs in a python module.   I would suggest reviewing that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)

Comment: Code runs from top to bottom, and mainloop is an infinite loop, so all code after it is unreachable. If you put it at the top of the program, you begin the main loop before setting anything up, so it's like saying "I'm ready to run my program, which does nothing". When you add it at the end, you're saying "Set up my program, then run the main loop once I've defined how it should behave".

Comment: That would be like moving into a house before it's built, while it is still an empty lot.

Comment: Also, `mainloop()`'s position at start or end would not be the cause of a syntax error. Syntax errors result from writing *syntactically* invalid code, while the positioning of `mainloop`'s call should only affect *logical* validity.

Comment: I don't see how this would be a syntax error. And its not so much that the rest of your code will be discarded as that it won't have had a chance to run.

Answer (score 0):

Python executes your file from top to bottom.   This includes setting global variables and defining classes and functions.  Putting the main_loop at the bottom allows for all that setup and definition to occur before you actually need it in the main_loop call.